# How to typeset a TikZ picture inside a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nesting

The contents of a node are drawn in text mode. Is there a way, short of introducing a `tikzpicture` environment, to draw a picture inside a node?

Nesting `tikzpicture` environments is [problematic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46598/8057), also because the inner environment [inherits all TikZ attributes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46818/8057) from the surrounding `tikzpicture` environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to take precautions to use nesting  `tikzpicture` but but it is doable.

You need to also take certain precautions to work with `tikzpicture` inside  `tikzpicture` or with `scope` inside  `tikzpicture`. Everything depends on circumstances and what you want to do but I think there is always a way to deal.

I work on the next document for [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47024/how-to-scale-and-clip-a-path-at-the-same-time/47230#47230). The problem here is to place automatically the heart and I need to use an extern node '(txt)' to place a node inside the tikzpicture inside a node. Well Tikz is magic and do that without problem

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,
            paperheight=8cm,
            margin=0cm,
            left=0cm,
            bottom=0mm]{geometry} 
%\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}   
\usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document} 
 \pagestyle{empty}   
 \setlength{\parindent}{0em} 

 \tikzset{text style/.style={align      = center,
                             text width = \textwidth}}    

\newcommand\mytext{The life that I have \\
Is all that I have \\
And the life that I have \\
Is yours. \\
The love that I have  \\
Of the life that I have \\
Is yours and yours and yours. \\

A sleep I shall have \\
A rest I shall have \\
Yet death will be but a pause.\\

For the peace of my years \\
In the long green grass \\
Will be yours and yours and yours.}

\null\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node[text style,color=red] (txt) {\mytext};

\node at (txt.center)     
{\begin{tikzpicture}[fill  = red]
\pgftransformscale{.025}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{3600 pt}{3350 pt}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{3580 pt}{4270 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{870 pt}{6400 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{990 pt}{7860 pt}}%     
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{1040 pt}{8430 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{1590 pt}{9060 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{2200 pt}{9060 pt}}%
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{3610 pt}{9050 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{3600 pt}{7720 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{3600 pt}{7720 pt}}%
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{3600 pt}{7720 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{3580 pt}{9050 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{4990 pt}{9060 pt}}%
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{5600 pt}{9060 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{6150 pt}{8430 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{6200 pt}{7860 pt}}%
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{6320 pt}{6400 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{3610 pt}{4270 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{3600 pt}{3350 pt}}%
\pgfpathclose            
\pgfusepath{clip,fill,stroke}%
%
\node[white,
     anchor = north west,
     text style] at (txt.north west) {\mytext};  
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\vfill
\end{document}
```

**Update**  I added inside a new tikpicture  inside a node inside a  tikzpicture inside a node inside the first tikzpicture with opacity , filling.

I created the ant.pgf from the ant of the pst-fun with some difficulties because original picture use `rlineto` and `rcurveto` and I don't know if it's possible with pgf.

[image]

```
 %  http://altermundus.com/SandBox/ant1.pgf       
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,
            paperheight=8cm,
            margin=0cm,
            left=0cm,
            bottom=0mm]{geometry} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter  
\newcommand{\callornament}[1]{%
\begingroup
\def\i{\pgfusepath{clip}}%
\let\o\pgfpathclose
\let\s\pgfusepathqfillstroke
\def\p ##1##2{\pgfqpoint{##1bp}{##2bp}}%
\def\m ##1 ##2 {\pgfpathmoveto{\p{##1}{##2}}}%
\def\l ##1 ##2 {\pgfpathlineto{\p{##1}{##2}}}%
\def\r ##1 ##2 ##3 ##4 {\pgfpathrectangle{\p{##1}{##2}}{\p{##3}{##4}}}%
\def\c ##1 ##2 ##3 ##4 ##5 ##6 {%
\pgfpathcurveto{\p{##1}{##2}}{\p{##3}{##4}}{\p{##5}{##6}}}%   
\@@input #1\relax
\endgroup}   
\makeatother

 \begin{document} 
 \pagestyle{empty}   
 \setlength{\parindent}{0em} 

 \tikzset{text style/.style={align      = center,
                             text width = \textwidth}}    

\newcommand\mytext{The life that I have \\
Is all that I have \\
And the life that I have \\
Is yours. \\
The love that I have  \\
Of the life that I have \\
Is yours and yours and yours. \\

A sleep I shall have \\
A rest I shall have \\
Yet death will be but a pause.\\

For the peace of my years \\
In the long green grass \\
Will be yours and yours and yours.}

\null\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node[text style,color=red] (txt) {\mytext};

\node (h) at (txt.center)     
{\begin{tikzpicture}[fill  = red]
\pgftransformscale{.025}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{3600 pt}{3350 pt}}
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{3580 pt}{4270 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{870 pt}{6400 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{990 pt}{7860 pt}}%     
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{1040 pt}{8430 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{1590 pt}{9060 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{2200 pt}{9060 pt}}%
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{3610 pt}{9050 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{3600 pt}{7720 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{3600 pt}{7720 pt}}%
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{3600 pt}{7720 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{3580 pt}{9050 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{4990 pt}{9060 pt}}%
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{5600 pt}{9060 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{6150 pt}{8430 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{6200 pt}{7860 pt}}%
\pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{6320 pt}{6400 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{3610 pt}{4270 pt}}
               {\pgfqpoint{3600 pt}{3350 pt}}%
\pgfpathclose            
\pgfusepath{clip,fill,stroke}%
%
\node[white,
     anchor = north west,
     text style] at (txt.north west) {\mytext}; 
\node at (txt.center){\tikz \pgftransformscale{.0125}%
                           \pgfsetfillcolor{MidnightBlue}%
                           \pgfsetfillopacity{.5}%
                           \callornament{ant1.pgf} ;};    
\end{tikzpicture}};

\end{tikzpicture} 
\vfill
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which question do you refer to? Could you please provide a link? -- Also, the question is more about _how to avoid it_, and not if it's doable or not...

Comment: As I was writing my comment, I noticed that my question was formulated badly. I'll start a new one. Thanks for the nice example, though.

Comment: Yes the question is badly formulated if you want to avoid  the tikzpicture inside a node but why to you want to avoid this ? Sometimes it's very useful to do this ! A node is useful to place something ( text, picture or tikzpicture) inside a tikzpicture!

Comment: I just don't want to bother with [resetting attributes to default values](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47377/8057).

Comment: It's the aim of my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46818/  We need to answer this question before to give a correct answer to yours

Comment: Well, I'm not asking for which attributes to save/restore. I'm asking if there's a way to save/restore _everything_. This could be possible if there were a way to iterate over all known TikZ/PGF attributes, and would be more generic/general that what you have asked for. Just another way of looking at the problem, I guess -- not intending to compete.

Comment: Which technique would you suggest  [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314174/2956) with nesting Tikz pics side-by-side where four pictures meant to be placed 2x2 grid? Instead of scope, I defined local variables for each node.