# How to avoid nesting of tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices

I have to draw the probability distribution function (PDF) in the following MWE multiple times in a figure as well as across multiple figures. I have read the following questions:

- [Problem with overlay when a tikzpicture is inside another tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture)
- [Nesting "tikzpicture" within "tikzpicture" elements - Good or bad practice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51193/nesting-tikzpicture-within-tikzpicture-elements-good-or-bad-practice)
- [How to typeset a TikZ picture inside a node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-typeset-a-tikz-picture-inside-a-node)

and think that I would like to avoid nesting if possible. This is a simple MWE and for this specific problem, I could use absolute positioning of all the elements. But it is cumbersome. Another option is prepare a PDF file and include the image in a node. Is there a better option?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2em]
    \node(pdf){
      \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw [step=0.25cm,lightgray,very thin] (0,0) grid (2.5,1.5);
          \draw [draw,->,ultra thick] (0,0.0) -- (0,1.5);
          \draw [draw,->,ultra thick] (0,0.0) -- (2.5,0);
          \draw [fill=blue!20!white,ultra thick,overlay] (0.2,0) ..controls
          (0.5,2.2) and (1,0.1) .. (2,0);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    };  
    \node [rectangle,draw, right=of pdf] (cfd) {Nonlinear Flow Solution};
    \path[draw,->] (pdf) -- (cfd); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way IMHO is to typeset the inner `tikzpicture` in a savebox outside the other `tikzpicture` and then use the box inside the node.
This way no settings of the parent `tikzpicture` will be picked up, because the inner one is already rendered.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw [step=0.25cm,lightgray,very thin] (0,0) grid (2.5,1.5);
          \draw [draw,->,ultra thick] (0,0.0) -- (0,1.5);
          \draw [draw,->,ultra thick] (0,0.0) -- (2.5,0);
          \draw [fill=blue!20!white,ultra thick,overlay] (0.2,0) ..controls
          (0.5,2.2) and (1,0.1) .. (2,0);
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{lrbox}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2em]
    \node(pdf){\usebox\mybox};
    \node [rectangle,draw, right=of pdf] (cfd) {Nonlinear Flow Solution};
    \path[draw,->] (pdf) -- (cfd); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to do this using a macro:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
      \normalfont% to ensure that the font is fully set up
      \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw [step=0.25cm,lightgray,very thin] (0,0) grid (2.5,1.5);
          \draw [draw,->,ultra thick] (0,0.0) -- (0,1.5);
          \draw [draw,->,ultra thick] (0,0.0) -- (2.5,0);
          \draw [fill=blue!20!white,ultra thick,overlay] (0.2,0) ..controls
          (0.5,2.2) and (1,0.1) .. (2,0);
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}
\newcommand\mypdfimage{\usebox\mybox}


\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2em]
    \node(pdf){\mypdfimage};
    \node [rectangle,draw, right=of pdf] (cfd) {Nonlinear Flow Solution};
    \path[draw,->] (pdf) -- (cfd); 
  \end{tikzpicture}

And again:

  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2em]
    \node(pdf){\mypdfimage};
    % [..]
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But here the macro is just a short-cut, you can use `\usebox\mybox` directly if you don't mind.

Comment: Can the lrbox be included in preamble as a `newcommand` with `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: @devendra: `lrbox` can be used inside the preamble, too, but you might want to add `\normalfont` in front of it to ensure that the normal font is already set up. It can also be used inside `\AtBeginDocument{..}` as long as you don't have any special content, like verbatim material, which isn't allowed in a macro argument. Not sure what you mean with "as a newcommand".

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of defining a new macro named `\pdffigure` and use it in all the figures. I will also have to look into scaling this box for different figures.

Comment: @devendra: You should place the `lrbox` environment inside a macro definition then. Simply use `\usebox\mybox` everywhere or define a macro which contains these two. Note that you will need a separate saveboxes if you want to have multiple inner pictures.

Answer (score 11):

If your situation is that the subpicture is specified *first* then you can use the `fit` library together with the `current bounding box` to put a node around the subpicture.

```
\documentclass{report}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89264/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2em]
          \draw [step=0.25cm,lightgray,very thin] (0,0) grid (2.5,1.5);
          \draw [draw,->,ultra thick] (0,0.0) -- (0,1.5);
          \draw [draw,->,ultra thick] (0,0.0) -- (2.5,0);
          \draw [fill=blue!20!white,ultra thick,overlay] (0.2,0) ..controls
          (0.5,2.2) and (1,0.1) .. (2,0);
\node[fit=(current bounding box)] (pdf) {};
    \node [rectangle,draw, right=of pdf] (cfd) {Nonlinear Flow Solution};
    \path[draw,->] (pdf) -- (cfd); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz subpicture using fit]

If not, there is an equally simple alternative (which I just found out about from digging in the code) which allows you to define a node around a given scope.  Simply put the `local bounding box=<name>` key on a scope and it will define a rectangular node around that scope.

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89264/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2em]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=pdf]
          \draw [step=0.25cm,lightgray,very thin] (0,0) grid (2.5,1.5);
          \draw [draw,->,ultra thick] (0,0.0) -- (0,1.5);
          \draw [draw,->,ultra thick] (0,0.0) -- (2.5,0);
          \draw [fill=blue!20!white,ultra thick,overlay] (0.2,0) ..controls
          (0.5,2.2) and (1,0.1) .. (2,0);
\end{scope}
    \node [rectangle,draw, right=of pdf] (cfd) {Nonlinear Flow Solution};
    \path[draw,->] (pdf) -- (cfd); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

One difference is that the node specified by the scope is "tight" around its contents:

[image: TikZ subnode with scope]

Comment: In the second approach, does the `scope` environment take `scale` option?

Comment: @devendra No idea - try it and see!

Comment: It works fine. I think that the second approach is better with a macro written to automate the process across all the figures.

Comment: I cannot place the pdf node relative to another node using `scope`. Say I wanted to place another pdf to the right of the text box then I cannot use `right=of cfd`. I tried. Without the possibility of relative node placement, this approach is of limited use.

Comment: @devendra I have some code to fix that in my TeX-SX answer directory but I can't locate the question to which it pertains (and it might not pertain to any question - I also use that directory as "scratch").  Worth another question ...

Comment: Solved the problem by using `\matrix` environment. No need for `positioning` library usage. Thank you.