# Unwanted shifts of contours of characters

Tags: tikz-pgf, contour

In [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63174/14500) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64473/121799), an nice method of clipping Ti*k*Z stuff against the contours of some characters have been proposed: use the character for `tikzfadingfrompicture` and then use that fading to clip away stuff that's outside of the contour. Overall, this works great but it seems that at large magnifications some manual shifts are required to obtain the desired result. Consider the MWE (that was triggered by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439673/121799))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,positioning}
\usepackage{contour}
\contournumber{32}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=5-0]
\node[transparent!0,scale=15] (5) at (0,0) {5};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=5-1]
\node[transparent!0,scale=15] (5) at (0,0) {5};
\path (5.south) -- ++ (0,-0.1);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[white,scale=15] (5-1) {\contour{blue}{5}};
   \foreach \x in {1,1.2,...,3.4}
   \foreach \y in {0.1,0.4,...,4.5}
   {
       \path[path fading=5-1,fit fading=false] 
       ({\x-2},{\y-2.5}) node {5};
   }
   \node[above=0pt of 5-1]{contour shifted by hand};
\end{tikzpicture}
~
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[white,scale=15] (5-0) {\contour{blue}{5}};
   \foreach \x in {1,1.2,...,3.4}
   \foreach \y in {0.1,0.4,...,4.5}
   {
       \path[path fading=5-0,fit fading=false] 
       ({\x-2},{\y-2.5}) node {5};
   }
   \node[above=0pt of 5-0]{contour not shifted};
   \draw[thick,red] ([yshift=-1.9cm]5-0.north) circle (1cm and 3pt)
   ([yshift=-3.1cm]5-0.north) circle (1cm and 3pt)
   ([yshift=-4.15cm,xshift=-0.75cm]5-0.north) circle (0.3cm and 3pt)
   ([yshift=-5.2cm]5-0.north) circle (0.5cm and 3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The left contour is what I would call the desired output but it seems to require a manual shift achieved by `\path (5.south) -- ++ (0,-0.1);` in the corresponding `tikzfadingfrompicture`. The right contour does not have the manual adjustment, and therefore there are gaps, which are marked in red, as well as overlaps, which are harder to see, and which I did not mark.

**Question**: Why is that? Am I doing something obviously wrong? And, most importantly, is there a non-manual way to fix this?

**Bonus question**: Is there a *simple* way to move the `path fading`, i.e. to make it work if I place the big 5 at an arbitrary point, not at `(0,0)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems `contour` lifts the node by half the contour line width, specified by `\contourlength`. In the code of `contour` this line width is stored in `\con@base@length`, so by lowering the contour node by half this value the small 5 and the contour 5 should align. Test (I also included one with scale 10 and (un-scaled) contour width 0.7pt):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,positioning}
\usepackage{contour}
\contournumber{32}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=5-0]
  \node[transparent!0,scale=15] (5) at (0,0) {5};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=5-10]
  \node[transparent!0,scale=10] (5) at (0,0) {5};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \makeatletter
  \node[white,inner sep=1pt,scale=15,yshift=-0.5*\con@base@length] (5-0c) {\contour{blue}{5}};
  \makeatother
  \foreach \x in {1,1.2,...,3.4}
  \foreach \y in {0.1,0.4,...,4.5}
  {
    \path[path fading=5-0,fit fading=false] 
    ({\x-2},{\y-2.5}) node {5};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\contourlength{0.7pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \makeatletter
  \node[white,inner sep=1pt,scale=10,yshift=-0.5*\con@base@length] (5-10c) {\contour{blue}{5}};
  \makeatother
  \foreach \x in {1,1.2,...,3.4}
  \foreach \y in {0.1,0.4,...,4.5}
  {
    \path[path fading=5-10,fit fading=false] 
    ({\x-2},{\y-2.5}) node {5};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason the  node is lifted by half the contour line is how `contour` sets the box around the text. From

```
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\Huge A}\fbox{\contour{red}{\color{white}\Huge A}}
```

[image]

one can see that it is lowered below the text but not increased in height (or width). When putting this in a node, it is aligned in the center, and the contour text will be lifted by half the line width.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (A) {\fbox{\Huge A}};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,right=of A] (Acol) {\fbox{\contour{red}{\color{white}\Huge A}}};  
  \fill[green] (A) circle (1pt);
  \fill[green] (Acol) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot I have added my interpretation of why it is lifted half line width.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Great research!!! (To me it seems also a bit odd that the bounding box is increased in this asymmetric way... )

Comment: Yes, I agree. I can understand that the depth of the text should increase with the line width. But that does not explain why the height is not increased.