# plus/minus signs look as 3D objects

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code to draw plus/minus signs

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\vspace {1.cm}
\draw [thick,orange,fill=yellow] (.25,.25) -- ++(0:.25) -- ++(-90:.25)-- ++(0:.25)-- ++(-90:.25)-- ++(180:.25)-- ++(-90:.25)-- ++(180:.25)-- ++(90:.25)-- ++(180:.25)-- ++(90:.25)-- ++(0:.25)-- ++(90:.25) -- cycle;
\draw [thick,green,fill=green](0,-1) -- ++(0:.75) -- ++(-90:.25)  -- ++(180:.75)-- ++(90:.25)-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives me

[image]

Is it possible to make them look as 3-D objects as any one of the following drawings?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is just a proposal; it can serve like a “base“ for further things:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=2cm] (a) {};
        \fill[red] ([xshift=-.5cm]$(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) -- 
                   ([yshift=-1.5cm,xshift=-.5cm]$(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) -- 
                   ([yshift=.5cm]$(a.north west)!.5!(a.south west)$) -- 
                   ([yshift=-.5cm]$(a.north west)!.5!(a.south west)$) -- 
                   ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]$(a.north west)!.5!(a.south west)$) -- 
                   ([xshift=-.5cm]$(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) -- 
                   ([xshift=.5cm]$(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) -- 
                   ([yshift=1.5cm,xshift=.5cm]$(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) --  
                   ([yshift=-.5cm]$(a.north east)!.5!(a.south east)$) -- 
                   ([yshift=.5cm]$(a.north east)!.5!(a.south east)$) --
                   ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=.5cm]$(a.north east)!.5!(a.south east)$) -- 
                   ([xshift=.5cm]$(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$) --
                   cycle;
        \draw[red!70!black,ultra thick] ([yshift=-.5cm]$(a.north west)!.5!(a.south west)$) --
                                        ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]$(a.north west)!.5!(a.south west)$);
        \draw[red!70!black,ultra thick] ([xshift=-.5cm]$(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) --
                                        ([xshift=.5cm]$(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) --
                                        ([yshift=1.5cm,xshift=.5cm]$(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) --
                                        ([yshift=-.5cm]$(a.north east)!.5!(a.south east)$) --
                                        ([yshift=.5cm]$(a.north east)!.5!(a.south east)$) --
                                        ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=.5cm]$(a.north east)!.5!(a.south east)$) -- 
                                        ([xshift=.5cm]$(a.north west)!.5!(a.north east)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT:** Here are some more examples:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0.02,-0.02) {Hier steht ein kurzer Text};
        \node[blue!70] at (0,0) {Hier steht ein kurzer Text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot]

And:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[blue,text width=1.5cm,align=center,draw,fill=white] (a) {\bf\LARGE\TeX\\[3pt]\normalsize Users\\Group};
            \draw[blue,shorten >=1.2cm,shorten <=.1cm] ([yshift=6]a.west) -- ([yshift=6]a.east);
            \draw[blue,shorten >=1.2cm,shorten <=.1cm] ([yshift=6]a.east) -- ([yshift=6]a.west);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \fill[blue] ($(a.north west)+(-.1,-.1)$) -- ($(a.south west)+(-.1,-.1)$) -- ($(a.south east)+(-.1,-.1)$) -- ($(a.north east)+(-.1,-.1)$) -- cycle;
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very lengthy, but it works fine.

Answer (score 9):

This is what works for [3D marmots](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=45973302#45973302)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9, transform shape]
\vspace {1.cm}
\shade [ball color=orange] (.25,.25) -- ++(0:.25) -- ++(-90:.25)-- ++(0:.25)-- ++(-90:.25)-- ++(180:.25)-- ++(-90:.25)-- ++(180:.25)-- ++(90:.25)-- ++(180:.25)-- ++(90:.25)-- ++(0:.25)-- ++(90:.25) -- cycle;
\shade [ball color=orange](0,-1) -- ++(0:.75) -- ++(-90:.25)  -- ++(180:.75)-- ++(90:.25)-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one enquiry please. Is it possible to control the colours for example using inner color= , outer color=; and center/angle of shading

Comment: @Hany No, for this kind of shading you can only set the `ball color`. But you could try other shading, e.g. radial fo which you can controll the colours with `inner color= , outer color=`

Comment: How to use radial shading?

Comment: @Hany By using `inner color= , outer color=`

Answer (score 5):

Really just for fun, using the tricks of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63174/121799) and [that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64473/121799). This works with [annotations of 3D ducks](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46031497#46031497). ;-)

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.text,calc}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{0.3pt}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{ugq}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\newsavebox\BlackHole

\newcommand{\blackHole}[1][1cm]{\tikz{%
\shade[ball color=black] circle(#1);}}
\sbox\BlackHole{\blackHole[0.6cm]}


\newcommand{\PlaceCharOverBlackHole}[2][20]{%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=temp]
\node[transparent!0,scale=#1] 
{\contour{black}{\bfseries\sffamily \textcolor{white}{#2}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]{\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,scale=#1] (X) {\contour{black}{\bfseries\sffamily 
\textcolor{white}{#2}}};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{1.2*max(width("#2"),height("#2"))/1cm}
\path[path fading=temp,fit fading=false,overlay,scale=\myscale] node {\usebox\BlackHole};}%
}

\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2709/121799
\def\SOUL@soeverytoken{%
 \PlaceCharOverBlackHole[2]{\the\SOUL@token}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\so{+}~\so{$-$}~\so{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\end{document}
```

[image]